# Oracle create package spec IS | AS

Tags: oracle, plsql, package

For the creation of an oracle package I can use the following two headers:

1. CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE IS ...
2. CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE AS ...

When do I use which header and what are the differences

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no difference, so you can use either keyword at any time. [The documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/create_package.htm#BABFGJAA) shows either can be used, for [any stored PL/SQL](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/sqlstatements.htm).

It's a matter of taste, and whether one form might sound/read slightly better, which can vary from statement to statement and is largely subjective.